# Inconsistency of default sort, pagination parameters name and logic in React Admin

Tags: react-admin

I have a simple front react-admin app, with a Flask API, and I'm trying to implement sort, filter and pagination in my API.

I'm using the dataprovider ra-data-json-server, and according to [this spec](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/v3.1.3/packages/ra-data-json-server), I have to implement it with "_sort", "_start", and "_end" parameters (with the underscores).

However, when I look at the GET query performed by my Front app, a sort and pagination will be something like:

```
https://balbla.com/#/users?filter=%7B%7D&order=ASC&page=1&perPage=10&sort=roles
```

which is consistent with the doc there https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html

So I'm troubled because:

- parameters names are different (the underscore)
- the pagination logic is quite different (end and start vs page number and page length).

Did I miss something or is there indeed an inconsistency? Which one to implement? For me, the easiest is to adapt my backend to the actual Front query format, but that's not the doc.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I also at first had the same confusion as you did, then I came across the source code for ra-data-json-server. It implements the _sort, _order, _start & _end. First of all, you need to have implemented sorting and paging in your API. I will advise you to use this ra-data-json-server Data Provider below:

```
import { stringify } from "query-string";
import { fetchUtils } from "ra-core";
/**
 * Maps react-admin que`enter code here`ries to a json-server powered REST API
 *
 * @see https://github.com/typicode/json-server
 *
 * @example
 *
 * getList          => GET http://my.api.url/posts?_sort=title&_order=ASC&_start=0&_end=24
 * getOne           => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * getManyReference => GET http://my.api.url/posts?author_id=345
 * getMany          => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123, GET http://my.api.url/posts/456, GET http://my.api.url/posts/789
 * create           => POST http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * update           => PUT http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * updateMany       => PUT http://my.api.url/posts/123, PUT http://my.api.url/posts/456, PUT http://my.api.url/posts/789
 * delete           => DELETE http://my.api.url/posts/123
 *
 * @example
 *
 * import React from 'react';
 * import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
 * import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
 *
 * import { PostList } from './posts';
 *
 * const App = () => (
 *     <Admin dataProvider={jsonServerProvider('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')}>
 *         <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
 *     </Admin>
 * );
 *
 * export default App;
 */
var __assign =
  (this && this.__assign) ||
  function () {
    __assign =
      Object.assign ||
      function (t) {
        for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
          s = arguments[i];
          for (var p in s)
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p)) t[p] = s[p];
        }
        return t;
      };
    return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
  };

export default (function (apiUrl, httpClient) {
  if (httpClient === void 0) {
    httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;
  }
  return {
    getList: function (resource, params) {
      var _a = params.pagination,
        page = _a.page,
        perPage = _a.perPage;
      var _b = params.sort,
        field = _b.field,
        order = _b.order;
      var query = __assign(
        __assign({}, fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter)),
        {
          _sort: field,
          _order: order,
          _start: (page - 1) * perPage + 1,
          _end: page * perPage,
        }
      );
      var url = apiUrl + "/" + resource + "?" + stringify(query);
      return httpClient(url).then(function (_a) {
        var headers = _a.headers,
          json = _a.json;
        if (!headers.has("x-total-count")) {
          throw new Error(
            "The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?"
          );
        }
        return {
          data: json,
          total: parseInt(headers.get("x-total-count").split("/").pop(), 10),
        };
      });
    },
    getOne: function (resource, params) {
      return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + params.id).then(
        function (_a) {
          var json = _a.json;
          return {
            data: json,
          };
        }
      );
    },
    getMany: function (resource, params) {
      var query = {
        id: params.ids,
      };
      var url = apiUrl + "/" + resource + "?" + stringify(query);
      return httpClient(url).then(function (_a) {
        var json = _a.json;
        return { data: json };
      });
    },
    getManyReference: function (resource, params) {
      var _a;
      var _b = params.pagination,
        page = _b.page,
        perPage = _b.perPage;
      var _c = params.sort,
        field = _c.field,
        order = _c.order;
      var query = __assign(
        __assign({}, fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter)),
        ((_a = {}),
        (_a[params.target] = params.id),
        (_a._sort = field),
        (_a._order = order),
        (_a._start = (page - 1) * perPage),
        (_a._end = page * perPage),
        _a)
      );
      var url = apiUrl + "/" + resource + "?" + stringify(query);
      return httpClient(url).then(function (_a) {
        var headers = _a.headers,
          json = _a.json;
        if (!headers.has("x-total-count")) {
          throw new Error(
            "The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?"
          );
        }
        return {
          data: json,
          total: parseInt(headers.get("x-total-count").split("/").pop(), 10),
        };
      });
    },
    update: function (resource, params) {
      return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + params.id, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
      }).then(function (_a) {
        var json = _a.json;
        return { data: json };
      });
    },
    // json-server doesn't handle filters on UPDATE route, so we fallback to calling UPDATE n times instead
    updateMany: function (resource, params) {
      return Promise.all(
        params.ids.map(function (id) {
          return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + id, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
          });
        })
      ).then(function (responses) {
        return {
          data: responses.map(function (_a) {
            var json = _a.json;
            return json.id;
          }),
        };
      });
    },
    create: function (resource, params) {
      return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
      }).then(function (_a) {
        var json = _a.json;
        return {
          data: __assign(__assign({}, params.data), { id: json.id }),
        };
      });
    },
    delete: function (resource, params) {
      return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + params.id, {
        method: "DELETE",
      }).then(function (_a) {
        var json = _a.json;
        return { data: json };
      });
    },
    // json-server doesn't handle filters on DELETE route, so we fallback to calling DELETE n times instead
    deleteMany: function (resource, params) {
      return Promise.all(
        params.ids.map(function (id) {
          return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + id, {
            method: "DELETE",
          });
        })
      ).then(function (responses) {
        return {
          data: responses.map(function (_a) {
            var json = _a.json;
            return json.id;
          }),
        };
      });
    },
  };
});
```